# How to find some words in a HTML page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a problem with this code:

```
textRange = [[html lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[substring lowercaseString]];
```

I'd like to find some words (substrings) in a HTML page. Using this method, I can find the words that are defined in "substring" but I want to find only entire words which are the substring to be searched for, and not any arbitrary (unbounded) occurrences of the substring. So I tried this method but nothing has changed:

```
textRange = [html rangeOfString:substring options:NSLiteralSearch];
```

Here's the entire code:

```
NSRange textRange;
textRange = [[html lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[substring lowercaseString]];
if (textRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    check++;
} else {
    // webView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: What about `[html rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", [string lowercaseString]]]`?

Comment: That won't detect lots of situations. E.g. In "<p>This is a 'word' in my sentence, or paragraph.</p>"), it wouldn't find the words "this", "word", "sentence" or "paragraph". Seems like regular expressions, or loop through finding the word with `rangeOfString` and checking the character before and after to make sure they're not alphabetic would be much safer.

Comment: I have also built an array using `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` and searched in that, but that's better suited for special cases (shorter strings in which you're searching, a smaller set of separators, etc.).

Comment: Finally, you might want to make sure you don't have to deal with html tags, e.g. do you need a search for "resume" to find hits such as "résumé" or "r&eacute;sum&eacute;". Personally, I do a html tag replacement and ASCII conversion before doing my searches.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and include `\b` at the start and end of the pattern to match word boundaries.